# Can I update just added row in MySQL with trigger based on condition?

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-insert

I need to update the salary of a newly added employee in the same table if condition is satisfied. SQL keeps throwing errors about syntax, if I use delimiter change it looks like this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER fixSalary
AFTER INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.salary < 50000 THEN
    UPDATE emp 
    SET salary = 5000 
    WHERE eno = NEW.eno;
END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

But it throws an error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'delimiter //
create trigger fixSalary
after insert on emp
for each row
begin
if ' at line 1"
```

I tried removing the delimiter:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fixSalary
AFTER INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.salary < 50000 THEN
    UPDATE emp 
    SET salary = 5000 
    WHERE eno = NEW.eno;
END IF;
END;
```

which resulted in another error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

I've tried all kinds of semicolons combinations with no luck. Can anyone help me to understand what's going on?

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: @ysth SQuirrel 4.4.0

Comment: You may not find anyone to help with that.  delimiter is something dealt with by the client, not the server.  Consider just using the command line mysql client to create your trigger.

Comment: Googling show many people having problems with this in squirrel; only hint to how to set the delimiter I saw was https://developer.jboss.org/message/959939#959939